# C# TFS Pull Request update Task in Code

Tags: c#, pull-request

Is there a way to move a task automatically with C# code (using Microsoft TeamFoundation plugin) from "Code Review" to "Done" upon a pull request?

If it is possible can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Do you already handle the PR programmatically and you need to move the task state?

Comment: Yes I am already handling the Task but I don't know how to get the Pull Request (Linked or not linked to the AR, if possible).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the PR programmatically in this way:

```
// for VSTS    
var connection = new VssConnection(collectionUri, credentials);
// for TFS On-Premise
var connection  = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(_serverUrl);
int pullRequestId = 11;
var client = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();
var pr = await client.GetPullRequestByIdAsync(pullRequestId);
```

Now you have th PR on your hand... you can check the status with the property `pr.Status`.

Note: maybe you need the reference `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi`.